# Ansible filter for json variable

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

A little background info. I'm using netbox as a source of truth for our network automation and I am currently in the process of doing some test to automate juniper configuration. Netbox is currently used as my ansible inventory and is supplying host_vars.

I want to achieve a simple task of setting a "value" in my Juniper configuration based on a host var.

## Problem

I'm most definetly using the wrong map/filter combination to achieve my goal of looping over the values within the dict "dns" but I've tried countless times without any success so taking my issue to the community for an advice.

### I have the following host_vars:

```json
{
  "ansible_host": "192.168.1.1",
  "config_context": [
    {
      "_utility": {
        "dns": [
          "10.10.10.10",
          "10.10.10.20"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "device_roles": [
    "leaf"
  ],
  "device_types": [
    "qfx5120-48y"
  ]
}
```

### And my task currently looks like:

```yaml
- name: Set DNS server
  juniper.device.config:
    config_mode: 'exclusive'
    load: 'set'
    lines:
      - 'set system name-server "{{ item }}"'
  loop: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility') | flatten | map(attribute='dns') | flatten }}"
```

Which is giving out a error message

Tried to debug it registering a variable and printing this using debug msg:

#### DEBUG

```yaml
- name: Print var
  vars:
    - nameservers: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility') | flatten | map(attribute='dns') | flatten }}"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ nameservers }}"
```

#### Result

```
ok: [poc-spine01-re] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "10.10.10.10",
            "10.10.10.20"
        ]
    ]
}
```

But when trying too loop over the values withing the result I get another error

#### DEBUG

```yaml
- name: Print var loop
  vars:
    - nameservers: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility') | flatten | map(attribute='dns') | flatten }}"
  debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ item }}"
  loop: nameservers
```

#### Result

```
fatal: [poc-leaf03-re]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: nameservers. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."
}
fatal: [poc-spine01-re]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: nameservers. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."
}
```

## UPDATE

Hi, it worked for the loop!. I've adjusted my variables and am now contemplating if i should only get the value of the key dns1 or dns2 ( not in a loop )

### host vars

```
{
  "ansible_host": "192.168.1.1",
  "config_context": [
    {
      "_utility": {
        "dns": {
          "dns1": "10.10.10.10",
          "dns2": "10.10.10.20"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "device_roles": [
    "leaf"
  ],
  "device_types": [
    "qfx5120-48y"
  ]
}
```

but can't get the map filter to properly display one value

### task

```
- name: Set DNS server
  vars:
    ns1: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility.dns.dns1') | flatten }}"
  juniper.device.config:
    config_mode: 'exclusive'
    load: 'set'
    lines:
      - 'set system name-server "{{ ns1 }}"'
```

### result

As you can see the value of 10.10.10.10 is quoted with brackets and a double quote instead of only the value string of 10.10.10.10

```
fatal: [poc-spine01-re]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "lines": [
                "set system name-server \"['10.10.10.10']\""
            ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop should be fixed as follow:

```yaml
    loop: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility.dns') | flatten }}"
```

Moreover I would add some extra filters to make sure that:

- you don't loop over the same dns twice if it is declared in several `config_context` entries (i.e. `unique`)
- you always go other the list in the same order (i.e. `sort`)

```yaml
    loop: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility.dns') | flatten | unique | sort }}"
```

## Side notes

> ```yaml
> - name: Print var loop
>   vars:
>     - nameservers: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility') | flatten | map(attribute='dns') | flatten }}"
>   debug:
>     msg:
>       - "{{ item }}"
>   loop: nameservers
> ```

Three problems in this single task.

1. Although it actually "works" with a list (which ansible automagically converts), your `vars` declaration should be a mapping:

   ```yaml
   vars:
     nameservers: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility') | flatten | map(attribute='dns') | flatten }}"
   ```
2. You are looping over the **string** `"nameservers"`. You want to loop over the content of the variable with that name:

   ```yaml
   loop: "{{ nameservers }}"
   ```
3. In your debug message, you are asking to print a list which first element content is whatever value is inside the `item` variable. What you actually want is print the content of that variable directly, which can be acheived with

   ```yaml
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item }}"
   ```

   or since you don't have any processing on the content by addressing the var directly

   ```yaml
   debug:
     var: item
   ```

Putting it all together and integrating my above fix which was the core of your question:

```yaml
- name: Print var loop
  vars:
    nameservers: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility.dns') | flatten | unique | sort }}"
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ nameservers }}"
```

Comment: You're comment fixed my initial queastion beautifully , so i was very glas with that! I ran into a problem with te module regarding how the device interpets data. I;ve updated the question to get a idea of how to extract the value of a key ( i've updated the host_vars a bit ) at the bottom of the original question. If you would like to suggest a possible way of doing this that would be awesome!

Comment: The expression you are using in your edit does not make much sense to me. What should happen when there are multiple `_utility.dns.dns1` entries in several elements inside a `config_context` list ?

Comment: there would likely never be another value within a config_context under _utility.dns.dns1.

wat my goal is is at this moment that that i want to extract the string value of dns1 and dns2 seperatly.

and like in my orginal question in a scenario i would like to loop over values.

in the future there will be more list like config_context._utility and dicts/key value pairs within those elements that i may need to use as a string or loop over if it's multiple values.

the main goal was learning how to do this correctly within ansible

Comment: Well in that case why do you make it a list ? Change it to a simple top level dict inside `config_context` and things will be much easier => `"{{ config_context._utility.dns.dns1 }}"`. With your current data structure, the above expressions are spitting out a list of all found values. If you want to keep it that way, just take the first (and only...) value: `dns1: "{{ config_context | map(attribute='_utility.dns.dns1') | first }}"` or simply point to the first (and only...) element in the list: `dns1: "{{ config_context.0._utility.dns.dns1 }}"`

Comment: Yeah that was my first idea to have it as a dict, but my netbox application puts everything I set in a config_context as a new list . Because you can have multiple config context assigned to things like (device-types, location etc.) If a host matches those assignments every config_context will pass it's top variables as a list.